# Stone-Cech compactification of completely regular noncompact space is not metrizable.

Tags: general-topology

I have problem with the statement in Munkres, topology (section28, 9)

If $X$ is completely regular and noncompact space
Then, $\beta (X)$ (Stone-Cech compactification of X) is not metrizable.

I solved this statement with condition normality of X. But I am still failed wih condition completely regularity. Could you give me some help??

Comment: [FYR](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2007&task=show_msg&msg=3013.0001)

Comment: The assumption $\beta(X)$ metrisable implies $X$ is normal, so we can assume $X$ is normal "for free".

Comment: Ah I didn't catch it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\beta(X)$ is metrisable. The assumption that $X$ is completely regular is necessary for $\beta(X)$ to exist. And $X$ is non-compact implies that there must be some $ p \in \beta(X)\setminus X$.

The supposed metrisability of $\beta(X)$ implies two things: there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ from $X$ such that $x_n \to p$ (as $X$ is dense in $\beta(X)$) and $X$ is normal (as $X$ is normal from being metrisable too, as a subspace of $\beta(X)$.

It follows from the convergence of the sequence (and the fact that we're in a Hausdorff space) that $A=\{x_2n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ and $B=\{x_{2n+1}: n \in \Bbb N\}$ are closed disjoint subsets of $X$, so by normality (and Urysohn) we have a continuous $f: X \to [0,1]$ with $f[A]=\{0\}$ and $f[B]=\{1\}$. By the fact that we're in $\beta(X)$ we can extend $f$ to a continuous $\beta(f): \beta(X) \to [0,1]$, but then we have a contradiction as

$$\beta(f)(p) \in \beta(f)[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{\beta(f)[A]} = \overline{f[A]}=\{0\}$$

but also

$$\beta(f)(p) \in \beta(f)[\overline{B}] \subseteq \overline{\beta(f)[B]} = \overline{f[B]}=\{1\}$$

So $\beta(X)$ is *not* metrisable.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is not normal, then $X$ itself is not metrizable (all metrizable spaces are normal), so neither is $\beta X$, since it contains $X$ as a subspace.